# I have a few questions about how Laravel works

Tags: php, laravel

I hope you are well. I am currently learning Laravel 8, and am of course encountering some small complications while learning. I would like to understand the following:

What does "{{ ... }}" mean? I understand the principle, of putting PHP in HTML, but how does it work? What does the "{{ }}" mean?

What does "@if", "@foreach" mean? I also understand the principle of putting a conditional aspect within a file, but what does "@" represent?

I have a particular problem, and when I search on the internet, I quickly come across PHP version problems (and I confess I don't believe it):

For example, I make a complete pagination system, and when I set up a foreach to set up my page numbers, it returns me an error:

```
@if ($paginator->hasPages())
<ul class="pagination">

    @foreach ($elements as $element)
        @if (is_string($element))
            <li class="page-item disabled"><span class="page-link">{{ $element }}</span></li>
        @endif
        @if (is_array($element))
            @foreach ($element as $page => $url)
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a href="{{ $url }}" class="page-link">{{ $page }}</a>
                </li>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    @endforeach

</ul>
@endif
```

Now, if I put this:

```
@if ($paginator->hasPages())
<ul class="pagination">

    @foreach ($elements as $element)
        @if (is_string($element))
            <li class="page-item disabled"><span class="page-link">{{ $element }}</span></li>
        @endif
        @if (is_array($element))
            @foreach ($element as $page => $url)
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a href="{{ $url  ?? '' }}" class="page-link">{{ $page  ?? '' }}</a>
                </li>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    @endforeach

</ul>
@endif
```

Now it works properly. If I replace the elements like the first text quote, then it's no longer a problem...

Could it be the cache? From the update of the server pages without restarting it with Laravel 8?

I thank you in advance for your help. I come here as a last resort, without knowing what to write on the internet, without finding a very logical and coherent answer...

Thanks

---

Typical example of an error that I have right away:

```
ParseError
syntax error, unexpected ' ' (T_STRING), expecting ')' (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Laravel/Site/resources/views/vendor/pagination/custom.blade.php)
```

In the code, I wrote this:

```
@if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
    
@else
    <li class="page-item">
        <a href="{{ $paginator->previousPageUrl() }}" rel="prev" class="page-link">
            Précédent
        </a>
    </li>
@endif
```

For it to work I have to put : `{{ $paginator->previousPageUrl()  ?? '' }}`

Comment: What error exactly are you getting?

Comment: That's [Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade) syntax, Laravel's template engine. They'll be replaced with their PHP pendant when being compiled. Somewhere in your `storage` folder I believe the "pure" PHP files exist

Comment: I don't see how the code you posted would cause a syntax error

Answer (score 3):

### Blade templates

Those "{{ ... }}" and "@" are just statements by which laravel template engine called **blade** knows what to do with provided statement.

You can read documentation of blade [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade).

> Blade's `{{ }}` echo statements are automatically sent through PHP's `htmlspecialchars` function to prevent XSS attacks.

"{{ ... }}" is called echo statement. So:

```php
{{ $variable }}
```

is translated to something like this:

```php
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($variable )?>
```

---

`@if`, `@for`, `@foreach` are replaced to something like this:

```php
<?php foreach($variable as $key => $value) { ?>
// template that you put inside
<?php } ?>
```

and so on.

---

### Null  coalescing operator

Errors with your functions that you claim that you have to put `?? ''` are caused that probably value of function / function itself is `null`.

The `??` operator checks for nulls (what you can read [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php)):

> The null coalescing operator (??) has been added as syntactic sugar for the common case of needing to use a ternary in conjunction with isset(). It returns its first operand if it exists and is not null; otherwise it returns its second operand.

Comment: Thank you very much for all these explanations that seemed a little unclear to me... It's not really the PHP I know, but it looks like a nice Laravel ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Laravel has a really good documentation, I recommend to go through the **The Basics** section where are covered core concepts like [routing](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing), [blade templates](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade) and so on.

Comment: Do I have a way to tell Laravel that the value is not null and that what I send it is necessarily correct? The person who shows the tutorial does not put the elements '  ?? '' ' ? How does she proceed, do you have an idea? Thanks again

Comment: There's not enough code and context for me to find error, there's many places from where the error could come. I would start searching the cause in [Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers) where you render the [view](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views) with this _template_.

Comment: This is my controller :

public function articles()
    {
        $articles = Article::paginate(4);
        return view('articles', [
            'articles' => $articles
        ]);
    }

Comment: Put it to the question together with the view & file names to make it easier to read.